# how to save logo into public folder

Tags: laravel

I have a problem to save image file to public folder

```php
$request->validate([
    'name'=> 'required',
    'email' => 'required',
    'logo' => 'required',

]);

Company::create($request->all());

return redirect()->route('company.dashboard')->with('Success');
```

Comment: im really new in laravel please help me

Comment: Your code doesn't save any file. Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
$image = $request->file('logo');
$path = public_path('/your_folder_name");
$image->move($path,$image->getClientOriginalName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you create a symlink from `storage/app/public` to `public/storage` with the command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Which makes you able to store your file in `storage/app/public` and access it publicly. you can use the `public_path()` helper to get the path.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = $request->file('logo');

if($file){
  $fileName = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalName(); //creating a file name
  $path = public_path('/logo"); //make a folder in public path logo.
  $file->move($path,$fileName);

  $request['logo'] = $fileName; //logo is your database field name
}
```

Comment: done but still not submit to database.No error but the data is not in the db

Comment: protected $table='company';
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'logo',
    ];

Comment: dd($request->all()); share result